# SAS MACRO Quoting issue : passing string with macro trigger as macro parameter

Tags: macros, sas, quoting

Is this possible to pass a string with macro trigger as the macro parameter?
Please see the example code below:

```
options mprint;
%let string5='%abc%def%';
%macro test(string);
data _null_;
    call execute('%test2('||&string.||')');
run;
%mend;

%macro test2(string2);
    data test3;
        a=%str(%')&string2.%str(%');
    run;
%mend;

%test(&string5);
```

This code ran successfully but it tried to invoke the macro %abc and %def, which resulted in warnings.

If I tried to put it into quoting to mask the string, it gave syntax error, as shown below:

```
options mprint;

    %let string5='%abc%def%';
    %macro test(string);

    data _null_;
        call execute('%test2('||%superQ(string)||')');
    run;
    %mend;

    %macro test2(string2);
        data test3;
            a=%str(%')&string2.%str(%');
        run;
    %mend;

    %test(&string5);

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, a missing value, arrayname, (, +, -, INPUT, NOT, PUT, ^, _NEW_, ~.
```

Is there a way to fix this without warnings?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? There may well be a simpler way of doing it.

Comment: I'm trying to pass the like pattern as a parameter, which contains %. What I am doing here is just an example.

Comment: Using `%nrstr()` is very useful when calling macros via CALL EXECUTE, but I am not sure if that matters for your problem.  `call execute(cats('%nrstr(%test2)(',symget('string'),')');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
%let string5='%abc%def%';
%macro test(string);
data _null_;
    call execute('%test2('||%nrstr("&string.")||')');
run;
%mend;

%macro test2(string2);
    data test3;
        a=%nrquote(&string2.);
    run;
%mend;

%test(&string5);
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. What bothers me is that %nrstr can only accept the constant text and won't resolve any macros, but it's not the case if the constant text is double quoted.

Comment: Correction, you mask it during compilation but let  it be resolved during the execution stage. This will solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually simple enough in the macro to protect against special characters. For example you can use the `%superq()` function to quote an existing macro variables value.

```
where name like %unquote(%str(%')%superq(parm1)%str(%'))
```

Or use the `symget()` function in a data step to get the value without needing to expand the macro at all.

```
pattern = quote(symget('parm1'),"'");
```

But the hard part is making the macro call. You need to protect the characters to get the macro call to run. You can use similar functions in the macro call.

One useful thing to do is to instruct users to pass the parameter value as a quoted string and then the macro code you can remove the quotes when they are not needed.

```
%macro mymacro(parm1=);
  %let parm1=%qsysfunc(dequote(&parm1));
  ...
%mend;
%mymacro(parm1='fred%')
```

Or you could ask them to pass the value by name.

```
%macro mymacro(mvar=);
  %local pattern ;
  %let pattern=%superq(&mvar);
  ...
%mend ;

%let my_pattern=%qsysfunc(dequote('fred%'));
%mymacro(mvar=my_pattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is already working the way you want and you just want to suppress this one warning message, you could consider setting `option nomerror;` before you run the section of code in question and then setting it back again afterwards.

Comment: Thanks but I would not prefer that as I can't anticipate the other warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the final solution I choose. I gave up the way to pass macro parameters between different macros, instead I passed the macro variable name as a string. Sample codes are as below:

```
options mprint;
%let string5='%abc%def%';

%macro test(string);
data _null_;
    call execute('%test2('||&string.||')');
run;
%mend;

%macro test2(string2);
    data test3;
        a=&&&string2.;
    run;
%mend;

%test('string5');
```